# Console logger with json formatter does not serialize objects

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, .net-5

I try to use default .NET core logging tools without any third party libs. So, question.
Does console logger with Json formatter support json serialization of objects?

I have the following config in appsettings

```
"Logging": {
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      },
      "FormatterName": "json",
      "FormatterOptions": {
        "SingleLine": true,        
        "JsonWriterOptions": {
          "Indented": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

The following line

```
logger.LogDebug("RequestId:{requestId} ResponseInfo: {@response} ", requestName, response);
```

produces the output with string representation of **@response** object, internally it still invokes ToString(), but docs in Caution section says that

> The logging infrastructure itself already manages the serialization of log messages, so if you're to pass in a log message that is already serialized—it will be double serialized
> [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#json)

And this point me that it should serialize object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the build-in `ILogger` don't support this. That's why we can [try the new System.Text.Json source generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-source-generator/).

[The new System.Text.Json source generator can improve logging performance.](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-8-improving-logging-performance-with-source-generators/)

---

I think we also can choose third-party package, like `Serilog`. That should be more easy to do this.

Comment: Looks like yes default logger don't support it. Finally I serialize object manually with System.Text.Json before passing it to log